# How a scalar component can be negative?

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors, geometry

[image]

I know that components of vectors are defined as being scalars. For example

```
        ax= a*cos(x)
```

Also I know that scalars cannot have a directions.
That is OK, but what is happening when we take 180°>x>90° like in photo.
What should I understand when I see a negative scalar. It feels like it has direction.How it doesn't?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Maybe but I do not know what exactly a vector means in math. I didn't take any serious linear algebra lesson. I saw vectors in just physics.Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\vec a_{\rm x} = -3\hat i$ can be interpreted in two ways.

$\vec a_{\rm x} = -3\,(+\hat i)$
Here the vector has a magnitude of $3$ - magnitudes are always positive, think of it as the length of the vector when drawn on a piece of paper.
The vector has a component of $-3$ in the $\hat i$ direction - in this case you have chosen a particular direction which is the direction of increasing $x$, $\hat i$, and the vector $\vec a_{\rm x}$ points in the opposite direction to $\hat i$.

$\vec a_{\rm x} = 3\,(-\hat i)=3\,( \hat {i'})$
As before here the vector has a magnitude of $3$.
The vector has a component of $+3$ in the $(-\hat i)$ or $(\hat {i'})$ direction - in this case you have chosen a particular direction which is the direction of decreasing $x$, $-\hat i$ or $(\hat {i'})$, and the vector $\vec a_{\rm x}$ points in the same direction as $(-\hat i)$ or $(\hat {i'})$.

Comment: nice explanation. But I have a question about your answer. if magnitudes always positive and scalars have just magnitudes and -3 is a scalar(scalars are numbers in R) -3 is positive?

Comment: To me $-3$ is a number on the number line just as $+3$ is on the number line.

Answer (score 1):

A scalar is just a regular number, and thus it can be positive or negative. Scalars themselves don't have directions but they define the direction of the vector that they generate.

Comment: Ok thanks. In school we learned a different story. Things are more clear right now.

Comment: So scalars can change the direction of a vector when we multiply a vector with them. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.